# What does Jetpack Compose remember actually do, how does it work under the hood?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

Checking out codelab's basic tutorial there is a snippet to increase counter on button when clicked

```
@Composable
fun MyScreenContent(names: List<String> = listOf("Android", "there")) {
    val counterState = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()) {
        Column(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
            for (name in names) {
                Greeting(name = name)
                Divider(color = Color.Black)
            }
        }
        Counter(
            count = counterState.value,
            updateCount = { newCount ->
                counterState.value = newCount
            }
        )
    }
}


@Composable
fun Counter(count: Int, updateCount: (Int) -> Unit) {
    Button(
        onClick = { updateCount(count + 1) },
        colors = ButtonConstants.defaultButtonColors(
            backgroundColor = if (count > 5) Color.Green else Color.White
        )
    ) {
        Text("I've been clicked $count times")
    }
}
```

It is clear that `remember { mutableStateOf(0) }` stores the state/value. My question is what remember does under the hood. Using  `var count = remember { 0 }` or `mutableStateOf(0)` without **remember** does not increase the value.

```
fun MyScreenContent(names: List<String> = listOf("Android", "there")) {
   
    var count = remember { 0 }

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()) {
        Column(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
            for (name in names) {
                Greeting(name = name)
                Divider(color = Color.Black)
            }
        }
        Counter(
            count = count,
            updateCount = { newCount ->
                count = newCount
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Snippet above does not update the value printed on `Text`, does remember only work with `MutableState`?

Comment: you can read my article to know what is does and how it does that https://medium.com/@thegoldycopythat/making-sense-of-compose-magic-deep-dive-b03873910a67

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan i read it. It's very good. You can add an answer based on your article.

Comment: thankyou , I'll find time to add the answer ,thanks for suggestion , you may also consider following on medium.

Comment: Really helpful, both the question and the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

`remember` - just allows you to remember state from a previous recompose invocation.
So, if you for instance randomize color at initial run. The randomized color is going to be calculated only once and later reused whenever re-compose is necessary.

And hence,

`remember` = *store the value just in case recompose is called*.

Now, the second important thing is knowing when `reCompose` should actually be triggered and there the mutable states come to help.

`mutablestate` = *store the value and in case I update value trigger, recompose for all elements using this data*.

Comment: From the materials I read about Compose, "remember" was very confusing.  I was given the impression that in order for a composable to recompose, a state variable must be remembered and used in that composable.  Now I get to understand that is not the case.  As long as the composable reads a mutable state I declare somewhere (inside ot outside of any composable codes) and as long as the state changes, the composable will recompose.  "remember is just for some simple stuff you do inside a composable like click a button and increment a number, otherwise, it's not needed in most of my cases.

Answer (score 54):

To learn how composition and recomposition works you can check out [Under the hood of Jetpack Compose article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/under-the-hood-of-jetpack-compose-part-2-of-2-37b2c20c6cdd) by Leland Richardson, which describes inner works very well, also youtube video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q9MtlmmN4Q0&t=11s). And most of this answer uses article as reference and quoted most from it.

The implementation of the Composer contains a data structure that is closely related to a [Gap Buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gap_buffer). This data structure is commonly used in text editors.

A gap buffer represents a collection with a current index or cursor. It is implemented in memory with a flat array. That flat array is larger than the collection of data that it represents, with the unused space referred to as the gap.

Basically adding space near your Composable function slot table to be able to update UI dynamically with high costs since `get`, `move`, `insert`, and `delete` — are constant time operations, except for moving the gap. Moving the gap is **O(n)** but this does not happen often which you need to change all UI structure, on average, UIs don’t change structure very much.

```
@Composable
    fun Counter() {
     var count by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
     Button(
       text="Count: $count",
       onPress={ count += 1 }
     )
    }
```

When the compiler sees the Composable annotation, it inserts additional parameters and calls into the body of the function.
First, the compiler adds a call to the `composer.start` method and passes it a compile time generated key integer.

```
fun Counter($composer: Composer) {
 $composer.start(123)
 var count by remember($composer) { mutableStateOf(0) }
 Button(
   $composer,
   text="Count: $count",
   onPress={ count += 1 },
 )
 $composer.end()
}
```

When this composer executes it does the following:

1. Composer.start gets called and stores a group object
2. remember inserts a group object
3. the value that mutableStateOf returns, the state instance, is stored.
4. Button stores a group, followed by each of its parameters.
5. And then finally we arrive at composer.end.

[image]

The data structure now holds all of the objects from the composition, the entire tree in execution order, effectively a **depth first traversal** of the tree.

So `remember` needed to store a `mutableState()` to get value from previous composition and `mutableState()` is required to trigger one.

And `MutableState` interface uses `@Stable` annotation

```
@Stable
interface MutableState<T> : State<T> {
    override var value: T
    operator fun component1(): T
    operator fun component2(): (T) -> Unit
}
```

> Stable is used to communicate some guarantees to the compose compiler about how a certain type or function will behave.
>
> When applied to a class or an interface, Stable indicates that the following must be true:
>
> 1. The result of equals will always return the same result for the same two instances.
> 2. When a public property of the type changes, composition will be notified.
> 3. All public property types are stable.
>    When applied to a function or a property, the Stable]annotation indicates that the function will return the same result if the same
>    parameters are passed in. This is only meaningful if the parameters
>    and results are themselves Stable, Immutable, or primitive.
>
> The invariants that this annotation implies are used for optimizations by the compose compiler, and have undefined behavior if
> the above assumptions are not met. As a result, one should not use this annotation unless they are certain that these conditions are satisfied.

Another [source with a Video](https://jorgecastillo.dev/jetpack-compose-effect-handlers) that describes how Compose works.

Comment: Neatly explained! This should have been the accepted answer!

Answer (score 14):

[Codelab example](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-basics#4) mentions about **remember** and **mutableState** as

> Reacting to state changes is at the very heart of Compose. Compose
> apps transform data into UI by calling Composable functions. If your
> data changes, you recall these functions with the new data, creating
> an updated UI. Compose offers tools for observing changes in your
> app's data, which will automatically recall your functions—this is
> called recomposing. Compose also looks at what data is needed by an
> individual composable so that it only needs to recompose components
> whose data has changed and can skip composing those that are not
> affected.
>
> Under the hood, Compose uses a custom Kotlin compiler plugin so when
> the underlying data changes, the composable functions can be
> re-invoked to update the UI hierarchy.
>
> To add internal state to a composable, use the mutableStateOf
> function, which gives a composable mutable memory. To not have a
> different state for every recomposition, remember the mutable state
> using remember. And, if there are multiple instances of the composable
> at different places on the screen, each copy will get its own version
> of the state. You can think of internal state as a private variable in
> a class.

`remember{X}` and `remember{mutableStateOf(X)}` are useful in different scenarios.

First one is required when your object doesn't need to be instantiated at each recomposition, and there is another trigger that triggers composition.

An example for this is `remember{Paint()}`, any object that doesn't need to be instantiated more than once or memory heavy to instantiate. If a Composable that possesses this object is recomposed, properties of your object don't change thanks to `remember`, if you don't use `remember` your object is instantiated on each recomposition and all the properties previously set are reset.

If you need a `trigger`(mutableStateOf) and need to have the latest value(remember) like in question choose `remember{mutableStateOf()}`

Answer (score 4):

Variables are cleared on every `compositon`.

Using `remember` will get the previous value.

I think its equivalent to declare a mutableState in ViewModel.

Comment: Any example in code snippet?