# Updating a Composable Function with a Lambda

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

In the Android developer docs at the following web address: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model#recomposition

There is a composable function which is given as the following:

```
@Composable
fun ClickCounter(clicks: Int, onClick: () -> Unit) {
    Button(onClick = onClick) {
        Text("I've been clicked $clicks times")
    }
}
```

It's said in the text that this produces an element which updates the number of times its been clicked every time it is clicked. However, looking at it, it seems to need a lambda function to do that.

When I try and put it into the SetContent function I get the following:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            WorkTimerTheme {
                Conversation(SampleData.conversationSample)
                ClickCounter(clicks = 0) {
                    //Insert My Function Here
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The comment `//Insert My Function Here` has been added by me. I presume that within this I have to put a Lambda which updates the clicks value of the composable, but I have no idea what to put. Does anyone know an acceptable way of writing this?

Comment: This is a pretty basic question about state in compose, I suggest you checking out [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state)

Comment: Thanks for the info! Personally I find the google docs pretty unruly as someone who is coming into everything a bit late. Answers to specific questions tend to give me more information, even if they are quite simple I think they help newcomers like myself and so are worth answering!

Comment: The docs are made especially for beginners! There's even a video with basic principles that might be more convenient for you.

Comment: It's possibly a mental block on my part in fairness! But more info on how to do the same thing can only be good for learning in my opinion, you could consider it a "worked example". I am watching the video now, it's actually very good, I will update my answer later to take this into account!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a `MutableState` to trigger recomposition and `remember{}` to keep previous value when recomposition occurred.

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65368007/what-does-jetpack-compose-remember-actually-do-how-does-it-work-under-the-hood) about it and my question contains answer to your question.

```
@Composable
fun MyScreenContent(names: List<String> = listOf("Android", "there")) {
    val counterState = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()) {

        Counter(
            count = counterState.value,
            updateCount = { newCount ->
                counterState.value = newCount
            }
        )
    }
}


@Composable
fun Counter(count: Int, updateCount: (Int) -> Unit) {
    Button(
        onClick = { updateCount(count + 1) },

    ) {
        Text("I've been clicked $count times")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks very much to @Thracian for linking a similar question. As the answer to mine is related yet slightly different I thought I would post my own.

The correct code is as follows:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {

            val counterState = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

            WorkTimerTheme {
                Conversation(SampleData.conversationSample)
                ClickCounter(clicks = counterState.value) {
                        counterState.value++
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As suggested I added a mutableState value which appears to remember the value of something at the last **"recomposition"**, unless it is explicitly updated. If a mutablestate **is** explicitly updated that will trigger a recomposition (as noted in the answer to @Thracian's question).

A **recomposition** will redraw the **Element**.

In order to update the value at **recomposition** the number of times the button has been clicked must be stored in the mutablestate and passed to the Composable Function at each **recomposition**.

Using the Composable functions Lambda argument to affect the mutable state completes the loop, updating the mutablestate which then recomposes the button with the updated value.

That is the purpose of `counterState.value++`.

As suggested above for more information on this, try reading this documentation: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#viewmodel-state

The video is related to what we're discussing here.