# Hold NavigationBottomItem in memory instead of destroying it in Jetpack Compose navigation when changing tabs

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

## Background

I am creating a chat application where I need to execute logic when the user leaves a chat (a chat is just a `@Composable fun` and I am using the `LocalLifecycleOwner.current` combined with a ViewModel which watches the `onDestroy` method to unsubscribe the user). Now that logic is also executed when the user changes tab, this should not happen.

## Problem

I am using a `Scaffold` with a `BottomNavigation`. When I switch tabs, the old tab is destroyed. I don't want this behavior, the old tab should remain in memory. The `remember` blocks are also re-executed when coming back to the tab, I don't want this. Should I use multiple navigation hosts or something?

## Goal

Navigating between tabs without `remember` blocks being re-executed (and also `LocalLifecycleOwner.current` should not publish `onDestroy`).

## Sample code

The whole project can be found here: https://github.com/Jasperav/JetpackComposeNavigation. You can see when switching tabs the `remember` blocks are re-executed and that the `VM` is destroyed (see logging). I don't want this behavior, it should be kept in memory. This is the relevant code:

```
@Composable
fun Screen() {
    val items = listOf(
        Triple("a", Icons.Default.Person, Icons.Filled.Person),
        Triple("b", Icons.Default.Notifications, Icons.Filled.Notifications),
    )
    var selectedTab = items[0]
    val navHostController = rememberNavController()

    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            BottomNavigation {
                items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
                    val isSelected = index == items.indexOf(selectedTab)

                    BottomNavigationItem(
                        icon = { Icon(if (isSelected) item.second else item.third, contentDescription = null) },
                        label = { Text(text = item.first) },
                        selected = isSelected,
                        onClick = {
                            navHostController.navigate(item.first) {
                                popUpTo(navHostController.graph.findStartDestination().id)

                                launchSingleTop = true
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    ) {
        NavHost(
            navHostController,
            startDestination = items[0].first,
            Modifier.padding(it)
        ) {
            composable(items[0].first) {
                selectedTab = items[0]

                val lifecycle = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
                val viewModel: ModelDontDestory = viewModel(factory = viewModelFactory {
                    ModelDontDestory(lifecycle)
                })

                remember {
                    println("Recomposed first")

                    ""
                }

                Text("first")
            }
            composable(items[1].first) {
                selectedTab = items[1]

                val lifecycle = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
                val viewModel: ModelDontDestory = viewModel(factory = viewModelFactory {
                    ModelDontDestory(lifecycle)
                })

                remember {
                    println("Recomposed second")

                    ""
                }

                Text("Second")
            }
        }
    }
}

inline fun <VM : ViewModel> viewModelFactory(crossinline f: () -> VM) =
    object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        override fun <T : ViewModel> create(aClass: Class<T>): T = f() as T
    }

class ModelDontDestory(val lifecycle: LifecycleOwner): ViewModel(), DefaultLifecycleObserver {
    init {
        lifecycle.lifecycle.addObserver(this)
    }

    override fun onDestroy(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        super.onDestroy(owner)

        println("This should never happen, this should be kept in memory")
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that keeping a `ModelDontDestroy` in your ViewModel is a memory leak, something [LeakCanary](https://square.github.io/leakcanary/) would tell you right away. You should never pass a Lifecycle to a ViewModel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have an object that remains in memory - the ViewModel instances themselves. You shouldn't ever be looking at the destruction of the Lifecycle instance, since that also happens when your app goes through a configuration change.

Instead, you should be looking at the `onCleared` method of the ViewModel - that's what is called only when the instance is actually removed from the back stack (e.g., the user leaves the chat).

Similarly, you shouldn't be using `remember` for state that needs to be saved (again, `remember` variables are wiped for many reasons, including when you do a config change). You should be using `rememberSaveable` for values that need to be retained for the entire time the screen remains on the back stack.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand of "[Lifecycle of composables](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lifecycle)" and from an example such as "[Implement Bottom Bar Navigation in Jetpack Compose](https://proandroiddev.com/implement-bottom-bar-navigation-in-jetpack-compose-b530b1cd9ee2)" by [Ziv Kesten](https://il.linkedin.com/in/ziv-kesten), the `remember` block ([explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65368007/6309)) and lifecycle events are inherently tied to the lifecycle of the `@Composable` function. When you navigate away from a screen, its `@Composable` functions are disposed of, and when you return, they are recomposed.

[image: Lifecycle of a composable in the Composition -- https://developer.android.com/static/images/jetpack/compose/lifecycle-composition.png]

In Jetpack Compose, the `remember` function is used to retain state across recompositions.
However, state saved using `remember` does not survive configuration changes or process death. If you need to retain state across configuration changes or process death, you should use the `rememberSaveable` function instead.

To use [`rememberSaveable`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#android_compose_state_hoisting-code-sample), you will need to ensure the data you're saving is serializable, as it will need to be [put into a `Bundle`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#android_compose_state_hoisting-code-sample).
As in:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyComposable() {
    val myState = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(MyState()) }

    // Use myState in your composable
}
```

`MyState` would need to be a data class with properties that are all serializable. The `rememberSaveable` function ensures that the state is saved and restored across configuration changes and process death.

However, in your provided code, it seems like you are using `remember` to trigger a `println` when the composable is recomposed. `remember` (and `rememberSaveable`) is not usually used for this purpose. Instead, `remember` and `rememberSaveable` are used to retain state across recompositions or configuration changes.
If you just want to print a log message when the composable is recomposed, you can just use `println` directly, without `remember`.
If you want to keep some state in memory, you can use `ViewModel` and `rememberSaveable` together, where `rememberSaveable` holds UI state and `ViewModel` holds more permanent data state.

That means this would be a more straightforward implementation:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Screen() {
    val items = listOf(
        Triple("a", Icons.Default.Person, Icons.Filled.Person),
        Triple("b", Icons.Default.Notifications, Icons.Filled.Notifications),
    )
    // Use rememberSaveable to persist the selected tab across configuration changes.
    val selectedTabIndex = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(0) }
    val navHostController = rememberNavController()

    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            BottomNavigation {
                items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
                    val isSelected = index == selectedTabIndex.value

                    BottomNavigationItem(
                        icon = { Icon(if (isSelected) item.second else item.third, contentDescription = null) },
                        label = { Text(text = item.first) },
                        selected = isSelected,
                        onClick = {
                            // Update the selected tab index when a tab is clicked.
                            selectedTabIndex.value = index
                            navHostController.navigate(item.first) {
                                popUpTo(navHostController.graph.findStartDestination().id)
                                launchSingleTop = true
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    ) {
        NavHost(
            navHostController,
            startDestination = items[0].first,
            Modifier.padding(it)
        ) {
            composable(items[0].first) {
                val viewModel: ModelDontDestroy = viewModel()

                Text("first")
            }
            composable(items[1].first) {
                val viewModel: ModelDontDestroy = viewModel()

                Text("Second")
            }
        }
    }
}

class ModelDontDestroy: ViewModel() {
    // Override onCleared to perform clean-up when this ViewModel is no longer needed.
    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()

        println("This should never happen, this should be kept in memory")
    }
}
```

With the changes:

1. Removed the `LifecycleOwner` from the `ViewModel`. The `ViewModel` does not need a reference to the `LifecycleOwner`. Instead, the `ViewModel`'s `onCleared` method should be used to perform clean-up when the `ViewModel` is no longer needed.
2. Changed `remember` to `rememberSaveable` for the selected tab index. This ensures that the selected tab is remembered even when a configuration change occurs (e.g., screen rotation).
3. Removed the `remember` blocks that were used to print a log message when the composable is recomposed. If you need to perform an action when a Composable is recomposed, you can just call that action directly in the composable. The `remember` function is not needed for this.